# Controlling paragraph spacing in LyX

Tags: spacing, lyx, paragraphs, koma-script

I'm working on a rather large document for my university using LyX. I have been using the `report (KOMA-Script)` document class.

According to my university's document specification each paragraph should have 6pts of spacing before and after it. Is there any simple way to do this?

I've looked around all of the settings provided in LyX and haven't found a solution. And I'm very new to LaTeX, so I do not really understand how to go about this.

Most of the document is written under the `Standard` Environment along with the appropriate chapters, sections and sub-sections. I need this `Standard Environment` text to have the correct paragraph spacing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your LaTeX preamble (which should be accessible in LyX through `Document -> Settings -> LaTeX Preamble`):

```
\KOMAoptions{parskip=half}
```

This will result in paragraph spacing equal to half the value of `\baselineskip` or (depending on the basic font size of the document) between 6pt and 7.2pt.